# What are the minimum requirements to run Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, requirements

I am looking to upgrade my system to *Windows 10 RTM*, but I'm afraid of losing performance.

I researched on the site but found details (maybe I have not sought duty) on the hardware minimum.

What are the minimum and recommended requirements for running Windows 10 RTM?

Comment: The requirements are identical to Windows 8.1

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications

Comment: That question doesn't look too similar, but the answer for this one could've just been googled...

Comment: @Ramhound I removed the "✓" to try to remove the question, I did not give downvote. Do not worry too sure differentiate things and I will not belittle any answers because of a comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no specific requirements to RTM. The specifications for Windows 10 are listed on the Microsoft [site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications).

> - Processor:  1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster processor or SoC
> - RAM:  1 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit or 2 GB for 64-bit
> - Hard disk space:  16 GB for 32-bit OS 20 GB for 64-bit OS
> - Graphics card:  DirectX 9 or later with WDDM 1.0 driver
> - Display:  800x600

Comment: There are also some more esoteric requirements of the processor.  It has to support CMPXCHG16b, and NX bit as well (most processors do, but some AMD chips do not)