# Can I install Windows 10 with given system details?

Tags: windows-10

The basic requirements of Windows 10 have been met and below is the current details of my system. So my question is whether the absence of EM64T and VT-X, that are otherwise considered important, affect the installation and working of Windows 10 in my system? Should I try to install Windows 10? I have a 64 bit AMD processor.

[image]

Comment: `VT-X` only exists on **Intel** products.  `VT-X` is also not required for Windows 10.  The requirements for Windows 10 is well documented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the minimum requirements to run Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/946488/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-to-run-windows-10)

Comment: There are other possible duplicates, that is just the first of many I found,  The comment by `Erik Funkenbusch` is very important.

Comment: The answer to [Windows 10 64-bit requirements: Does my CPU support CMPXCHG16b, PrefetchW and LAHF/SAHF?](http://superuser.com/questions/931742/windows-10-64-bit-requirements-does-my-cpu-support-cmpxchg16b-prefetchw-and-la) better explains the CPU requirements of Windows 8.1+

Comment: @Ramhound sorry but I couldn't understand anything from the above mentioned links. So I ask for your advise. Whether installing Windows 10 without these specs cause me any performance issues or something like that in the future?

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is whether the absence of EM64T and VT-X, that are
>   otherwise considered important, affect the installation and working of
>   Windows 10 in my system?

Neither of those extensions are required for Windows.  They are both Intel extensions to x86, you have an AMD CPU, and your CPU has the AMD versions of those extensions.

Windows 8.1+ requires a CPU with support for the following x86 extensions

> 1. CMPXCHG16B
> 2. PREFETCHW (connected to AMD's 3DNow! instruction set)
> 3. LAHF AND SAHF (related to 64-bit)
> 4. Enhanced Virus Protection

Your CPU does support NX-Bit which is required to run Windows 8.1+

> Enhanced Virus Protection, sometimes called NX-bit

[image]

> Should I try to install Windows 10? I have a 64 bit AMD processor.

See the below explaination from this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/931742/windows-10-64-bit-requirements-does-my-cpu-support-cmpxchg16b-prefetchw-and-la/941175#941175).

> You generally only need to be concerned about these instructions if
>   you have a processor that predates the above. The Get Windows 10 app
>   will tell you if you can upgrade to Windows 10. If the processor
>   doesn't meet requirements, you'll get "The CPU isn't supported."

Just use [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-compatiblity-report-means) application to determine if system can or cannot run Windows 10.  The RTM build of Windows 10 has identical hardware requirements as Windows 8.1 hence the reason I linked to them.

Source:

[AMD E1-Series E1-1200](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bobcat/AMD-E%20Series%20E1-1200.html)

[Windows 10 64-bit requirements: Does my CPU support CMPXCHG16b, PrefetchW and LAHF/SAHF?](https://superuser.com/questions/931742/windows-10-64-bit-requirements-does-my-cpu-support-cmpxchg16b-prefetchw-and-la)

[System requirements - Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12660/windows-8-system-requirements)

Comment: Apparently nobody fact checks answers anymore.  This answer for the better part of a year indicated this processor didn't support Windows 8.1 and newer when it actually did.